# How to configure apache with suPHP and VirtualHosts to avoid DocumentRoot problem?

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, suphp

I am currently configuring an apache web server, and have Apache 2.2 with SSL, svn at https://myhost/svn/repos/myrepo1 and https://myhost/awebsite with suPHP ready.  https://myotherhost/ also exists at the same IP address.

The problem is as follows: I have the website `https://myhost/` confined to `/home/myhost/public_html` with Apache's `VirtualHost` and `DocumentRoot`, and I need `https://myhost/websvn/` to reside in a different directory (`/home/svn/public_html/websvn/`) and belong to a different Linux user.  Since this second URI is also on the host `myhost` its `DocumentRoot` is applied by `(su)?php` and I get the following 500 error:

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:221: File "/home/svn/public_html/websvn/index.php" is not in document root of Vhost "/home/myhost/public_html"
```

I suppose one way to avoid this would be to disable checking (by setting `check_vhost_docroot=false` in `suphp.conf`), which I do not want for security reasons.

So: Is there a way to change suPHP's `DocumentRoot` for a given Apache `Alias` e.g. via `<Directory>` directives?  I have tried and found nothing even after a lot of searching.

Comment: This question may be more at home at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?  I cannot move the question myself, could someone who can please do it if you agree?